# How do I add a custom build step to Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

There doesn't seem to be a way to tie into whatever tooling that Angular CLI is using under the hood in order to build / serve a website.

I'm wanting to run my own image optimization script and can't find a way to run a script and a given point in time or add my code to the default build script.

Is there a way recommended / canonical way to do this?

Comment: did u mean something like ng eject ?

Comment: Are you trying to optimize the images you plan to serve with the site?

Comment: That's correct! Basically adding imagemin with creating webp versions and the like.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, Angular CLI does not support "pre" and "post" build events natively. However you could use one of other two options:

1. "pre/post" NPM scripts (more details: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts#pre--post-scripts)

```json
{
  "prebuild": "additional calls",
  "build": "ng build"
}
```

2. Switching to Nx tools (https://nx.dev/getting-started/intro) that have more support for build pipelines, especially "dependsOn" attribute to allow chaining the steps

Example: https://nx.dev/core-features/run-tasks#defining-the-task-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

If you want to optmize images then you can simply run script `post-build` and process assets in dist folder using any commandline tool you want. This is the most simple and reliable way.

Another option is to use `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` which allows to alter webpack configuration. You may want to see current cli config: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/main/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/webpack/configs.

It can make upgrading Angular more difficult, plus angular-cli can potentialy move to esbuild and `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` will be abandoned.